# Ipython default color scheme in sublime

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, jupyter-notebook

I would like to know how to get my sublime python editor to have the same color scheme as the default one in ipython. I started coding python in ipython (now jupyter) and literally any other color scheme feels so unnatural to me... I pictured what the color scheme I am talking about looks like below:

[Default ipython color scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUJsj.png)

I'm just hoping for a name of a color scheme I can install and activate in Sublime to get the same colors / experience. I have researched this extensivley and cannot find an answer... Thank you!

Comment: Agreed. That's 3 of us now. One of us should just make it.

Answer (score 1):

Closest I found to this was by going:

Preferences -> Color Scheme -> Color Scheme - default -> IDLE

Which is the IDLE dark on white color scheme.